# Is there a solution to this ODE: $ax'' - bx^γ+c = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have arrived here when analysing the adiabatic oscillations of a piston in a cylinder with (pressurised) air behind it and and a vacuum in front, with the pressure force from the air on the piston balanced by a weight on a cable over a pulley.

I have found an approximate solution for values of $a$, $b$ and ω in the form of $x = a + b \cos(ωt)$ using numerical methods and a spreadsheet, but am curious to know if there is a calculus solution to the ODE or if the numerical approximation is the only answer. I have reviewed the literature and am unable to find a clue to the solution.

Please note, this is not a homework question, it is a problem I have arrived at in my private study of gas properties.

Comment: Well there's technically a solution? Except the integral is nonelementary so there's really not much hope in finding an analycial expression for it lol. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a+y%27%27%28x%29+-+b+y%28x%29%5Ed%2Bc+%3D+0

Answer (score 1):

First, if $a = 0$ and/or $b = 0$, the equation simplifies to an immediately solvable one, so henceforth we assume $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$.

Now, for special values of $\gamma$ one can integrate explicitly to find general solutions; in all cases $C, D$ are constants of integration.

- $\gamma = 0$:
  $$x(t) = \frac{b - c}{2 a} t^2 + C t + D .$$
- $\gamma = 1$:
  $$x(t) = C \exp \left(\sqrt\frac{b}{a} t\right) + D \exp \left(-\sqrt\frac{b}{a} t\right) + \frac{c}{b} ,$$
  if $\frac{a}{b} > 0$; the other case can be integrated similarly.
- $\gamma = 2$:
  $$x(t) = \frac{6 a}{b} \wp\left(t + C, \frac{b c}{3 a^2}, D\right) ,$$ where $\wp(z, g_2, g_3)$ is the [Weierstrass $\wp$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function).

Henceforth we'll assume $\gamma \not\in \{0, 1, 2\}$, and for concreteness, we'll assume $a, b, c$ are all positive, but the other cases can be handled similarly. By scaling the independent and dependent variables, for $\gamma \neq -1$ we may as well assume that $a = 2, b = \gamma + 1, c = 1$, so that the equation becomes $$2 x'' - (\gamma + 1) x^\gamma + 1 = 0$$
Multiplying both sides by $x'$ and integrating once gives
$$(x')^2 - x^{\gamma + 1} + x = d$$
for some constant $d$ depending on the initial conditions.

We see that any value $x_0$ satisfying $x_0^{\gamma + 1} - x_0 + d$ defines a constant solution $x(t) = x_0$.

Rearranging the integrated equation gives
$$x' = \pm \sqrt{x^{\gamma + 1} - x + d} .$$
In particular, we've reduced the original equation to a separable first-order equation and so can write a generic solution as
$$t = \pm \int^x \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^{\gamma + 1} - s + d}} .$$

For most values of $\gamma$, this integral does not have a closed-form antiderivative. For $\gamma = 3$ the quantity under the radical is a quartic polynomial and so generically expression the solution requires using elliptic functions or the equivalent, and the cases $\gamma = -3, -2, \pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm \frac{1}{3}$ should be similar.

If $\gamma = -1$, proceeding similarly gives the solution $$t = \pm \int^x \frac{ds}{\sqrt{\log s - s + d}} .$$ The equation also admits the constant solution $x = \frac{1}{d}$ if $d \neq 0$.

We can probably find explicit solutions for particular (but not all) values of $\gamma$ in the special case that $d = 0$.

Comment: γ, is from thermodynamics and for air has the value 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x(t)$, you can reduce the order of the differential equation swithching variables
$$-a\frac {t''}{[t']^3}-b x^\gamma +c=0$$
$$p=t' \quad \implies \quad p=t'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a (\gamma +1)}{2 x \left(b x^{\gamma }-c (1+\gamma)
   \right)+K_1} }$$

I do not think that we could go futher *except* if $c=0$. In such a case, the solution would be given in terms of a Gaussian hypergeometric function.